# custom pickerview does not get scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios6, uipickerview, xcode4.6

I have created a custom picker view with xib which loads a data from the array and displays it properly. Now my problem is, this picker view does not get scrolled. Actually this picker view is loaded on to another view. So when i click into the picker view, the click appears to be on the base view on which this has been loaded.
Below is the code. Can any one please tell how do i correct this problem. Thanks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class PickerView;

@protocol PickerViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) didSelectValueAtIndex;

@end

@interface PickerView : UIView <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<PickerViewDelegate> PickerViewDelegate;

-(id) showPickerView : (UIButton *) senderButton dataArray: (NSArray *) dataArray viewframe: (CGRect) viewFrame;
-(void) hidePickerView : (UIButton *) senderButton;
@end


#import "PickerView.h"

@interface PickerView ()
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray * pickerData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *button;
@end

@implementation PickerView
@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize PickerViewDelegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) showPickerView : (UIButton *) senderButton dataArray: (NSArray *) dataArray viewframe:(CGRect)viewFrame{
    self.button = senderButton;
   self.pickerView = (UIPickerView *)[super init];

        if (self) {

            //inorder to load xib
            NSArray *theView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickerView" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *pickerviewLoadedFromXib = [theView objectAtIndex:0];

            CGRect btn = senderButton.frame;
            self.pickerData = dataArray;

            pickerviewLoadedFromXib.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x , btn.origin.y+ viewFrame.size.height, pickerviewLoadedFromXib.frame.size.width, pickerviewLoadedFromXib.frame.size.height);


            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            pickerviewLoadedFromXib.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, 200);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            [senderButton.superview addSubview:self];
            [self addSubview:pickerviewLoadedFromXib];
            }

    return self;
}

-(void) hidePickerView : (UIButton *) senderButton{

    NSLog(@"hide picker view");
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerData.count;
}

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"selectd value %@", [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row]);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pickerviewLoadedFromXib.delegate = self;
pickerviewLoadedFromXib.dataSource = self;
```

Pop these two in after you get the pickerviewloadedfromxib variable...